# must this extension of a DVR be unramified?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a normal domain, and $P$ a height 1 prime, then $A_P$ is a DVR. Let $K$ be the fraction field of $A_P$, and let $L$ be a finite Galois extension of $K$ of degree $e$, let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$, and suppose there is only one prime of $B$ lying over $P$ - call this prime $Q$. Further suppose that the extension of DVRs $A_P\hookrightarrow B_Q$ is totally tamely ramified (ie, ramification index $e$ coprime to all residue characteristics of $A$). Then, by Serre, Local Fields, I, Prop 18, $B_Q = A_P[T]/(f)$, where $f$ is an Eisenstein polynomial over the DVR $A_P$. In fact, by possibly multiplying $T$ by some element of $A \setminus P$, we may assume the coefficients of $f$ lie in $A$.

Now suppose $P$ is the only height 1 prime of $A$ above which $B$ is ramified. Let $P'\ne P$ be another height 1 prime of $A$. Must $A_{P'}[T]/(f)$ be unramified over $A_{P'}$?

Comment: T is just a transcendental, whose behavior is determined by the polynomial f that it satisfies. This polynomial is determined by the behavior of the extension above the prime P. The question is if the same polynomial determines an extension which is unramified above P'